# DLL implicit linking

Tags: c, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I cannot implicitly link DLL to C console application.
I use Visual Studio 2008.

I created empty DLL project "Library" which contains only one file main.c:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int get_value()
{
    return 123;
}
```

I also created empty console project "CallingProgram" with file main.c:

```
__declspec(dllimport) int get_value();

void main()
{
    int result = get_value();
}
```

I added "Library.lib" to "Linker\Input\Additional Dependencies".

And still I have this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_value referenced in function _main
```

I tested created DLL with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress - it works fine.

I checked Library.dll using DumpBin and it also looks good:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file library.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Library.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5340072C time date stamp Sat Apr 05 17:37:48 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011109 get_value = @ILT+260(_get_value)

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

Please help me understand what is missing!

Comment: Use dumpbin.exe /all on the .lib file to see what it contains.  Shooting from the hip, I'd guess that you built the DLL from a C++ source code file and try to use it in a C program.  That requires `extern "C"` to suppress the identifier name mangling.

Comment: I don't know what to do with all that information from dumpbin. I tried extern "C" - it did not help.

Comment: Sigh.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports on the .dll file, that's short enough to copy/paste into your question.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I did "DumpBin /exports Library.dll" and added results to the text of the question. To me it looks good. I tested Library.dll using functions LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress and it worked. That is why I assume that there is something wrong with Library.lib file. Please let me know what do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1    0 00011109 get_value

The symbol does not have its normal decoration.  It would normally be `_get_value`, all cdecl functions get a leading underscore.  And using `__declspec(dllexport)` also provides the `__imp_get_value` export.  It is a function pointer that optimizes the binding.

But that did not happen, you must have used a .def file in your library project.  Which *renames* exported functions.  Which is okay, but now your `__declspec(dllimport)` is incompatible, the DLL no longer exports the `__imp_` function pointer.  The linker complains because it cannot find it the import library.

Fix this either by removing the .def file from your library project (best) or by deleting the __declspec(dllimport) attribute from the declaration in your exe project.  Writing a .h file that declares the exported functions in the DLL is also highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is fascinating how you managed to figure it out. DEF file was root of my troubles - I removed it from project but it remained in "Linker\Input\Module Definition File" field.